# Some Rummikub rules say melds with jokers can be split, but can the joker be split off?

Tags: rummikub, joker

I'm not "picking up" or replacing the joker. I'm using it as its assigned value, and not claiming it as a wild card.

So if there's a sequence on the board of

567J

And I have two eights, so I split to above sequence to make

567 J88

Is that legal? Picture attached.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is legal.

From [2019 Rummikub rules](https://rummikub.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/12/2600-English-1.pdf):

> Sets can be manipulated in many
> ways (examples follow) as long as at the end of each round only legitimate sets remain and no loose tiles
> are left over.

There are 4 ways to clear a joker from a meld:
[image]